# For loop function is looping too many times

Tags: r

I am calculating a community weighted mean of functional trait values (studying forestry). I have to multiply the relative abundances of each species (tree) by the trait values. I have 2dataframes, 1 with the relative abundances of each species within each site and one with the average trait values for each species. I made a loop to automize the calculation, but the endresults return the multiplication 13 times instead of 1 time (I have 13plots, so maybe it has something to do with this) I'm already busy with this script for several days since i'm new to R, but i have to do this for my masterthesis. I think I reached my limit of logical thinking today and can't find my error :) can someone help me please? I'll paste the script below:

## load data, apply some column names, fill NAs with 0

```
library(data.table)
traits <- read.csv("Trait value.csv", sep = ";")

plots_Maiz <- read.csv("CWM Maiz plot.csv", sep = ";")

plots_Maiz[is.na(plots_Maiz)] <- 0

colnames(plots_Maiz) <- c("site", "species","y0","y1", "y2", "y3", "y4",    "y5")

traits[,1:17][is.na(traits[,1:17])] <- 0

#function for finding the corresponding species for a plot in the traitlist



       traitsf <- function(df, traitlist){
plottraits <- subset(traitlist, species %in% df[,2])
return(plottraits)
}

traitcalc <- function(traits, plots_Maiz){

multlist <- list()
blist <- list()
vmult <- vector()
tickcount <- 0

plotsplit <- split.data.frame(plots_Maiz, plots_Maiz$site)
testlist <- lapply(plotsplit, traitsf, traitlist = traits)


for (q in 1:length(plotsplit)){
df1 <- testlist[[q]]
df2 <- plotsplit[[q]]

plot <- as.character(plotsplit[[q]][1,1]) 


for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  
  v <- as.numeric(as.vector(t(df1[i,2:ncol(df1)]))) 
  
  species <- as.character(df1[i,1]) 
  
  
  for (j in 1:(ncol(df2)-2)){
    
    tickcount <- tickcount + 1
    vmult <-as.vector(v * (as.numeric(as.vector(df2[i,j+2])))) 
    
    vmult <- as.list(c(vmult, j-1, species, plot)) 
    
    
    multlist[[tickcount]] <- vmult 
    
  }  
}

b <- do.call(rbind, multlist) 
b <- data.table::rbindlist(multlist)


blist[[q]] <- b 

}

return(blist)
}

endresults <- traitcalc(traits,plots_Maiz) 
endresultsdf2<- do.call("rbind", endresults)
```